# How to get the visibility of gridlines from an axis?

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple plots and want to have a function which toggles the visibility of the grid lines for a selected plot. So far I can set the visibility depending on an defined input value (True/False). But I want to toggle the grid lines, because the plots are dynamically generated/destroyed.

I looked through the matplotlib-api, but haven't found a function which returns the visibility of the grid. `ax.xaxis.get_gridlines()` returns a list of grid lines, but gives no information about the visibility.

My code so far:

```
def toggle(key, val):
    if key == "grid":
        ax.grid(val)
    elif key == "xgrid":
        ax.grid(val, axis="x")
    elif key == "ygrid":
        ax.grid(val, axis="y")
    redraw()
```

It would be nice to retrieve the visibility like:

```
visibility = ax.grid.get_visibility()
ax.grid(not visibility)
```

Otherwise I would need to store the visibility values in a list to toggle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: The visibility can be found in `ax.yaxis._gridOnMajor` for the "major" grid. I don't know what the difference between major/minor is, but it works.

Toggling can be achieved by:

```
ax.xaxis.grid(not ax.xaxis._gridOnMajor)
```

Note: _gridOnMajor is a protected member of the (x/y)axis class; so one should be careful in accessing